# Convert If/Else's into a switch somehow

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement

So basically what I'm trying to do it turn this chunk of code into a switch statement somehow. I'm not really sure how to do this. I had a couple of ideas like making an enum with keywords that had a range of values (ie "enum hare { ONE =(range from 1-5) TWO = (range from 6-8)} - But i dont know if that is an error :S

Hopefully I've been clear in what I'm trying to ask.

```
int y = 1 + rand() % 10; 
    // determine which move to make
    if ( y == 1 || y == 2 ) {  
        hare += 0;
    } else if ( y == 3 || y == 4 ) {  
        hare += 9;
    } else if (y == 5) {
        hare -= 12;
    } else if (y >= 6 && y <= 8){
        hare += 1;
    } else if (y == 9 || y == 10){
        hare -= 2;
    }else {                         
        ++( hare );  
    }

    if ( hare < 1 ) {
        hare = 1;
    } else if ( hare > RACE_END ) {
        hare = RACE_END;
    }
```

Comment: For extra credit, learn the new C++11 randomization engine.

Answer (score 3):

The first question is whether there is real value in doing the conversion. Then the operation is actually simple for this case, since in all cases except the `else` there is a small number of valid cases:

```
switch (y) {
case 1: case 2:
   break;
case 3: case 4:
   hare += 9;
   break;
case 5:
   hare -= 12;
   break;
case 6: case 7: case 8:
   hare += 1;
   break;
case 9: case 10:
   hare -= 2;
   break;
default:
  ++hare;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `switch` statement, you can do like this

```
switch( y ){
    case 1:
    case 2: hare += 0; break;
    case 3:
    case 4: hare += 9; break;
    case 5: hare -= 12; break
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8: hare += 1; break;
    case 9:
    case 10: hare -= 2; break;
    default: ++(hare);
}
```

But, using `enum`, `enum hare { ONE =(range from 1-5) TWO = (range from 6-8)}` is that ... you are trying to store **multiple values** in **one variable**, which is not possible.

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) for `switch` statement

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do something like this:

```
     switch(y)
    {
         case 1:
         case 2:
             //do something
              break;

         default:
              //
    }
```

Therefore falling through your case conditions according the values of **y**.

Answer (score 2):

```
int y = 1 + rand() % 10; 

switch ( y )
{
case 1:
case 2:
    hare += 0;
    break;
case 3:
case 4:
    hare+= 9;
    break;
case 5:
    hare -= 12;
    break;
case 6:
case 7:
case 8:
    hare += 1;
    break;
case 9:
case 10:
    hare -= 2;
    break;
default:
    ++hare;
    break;
}

 if ( hare < 1 ) {
        hare = 1;
    } else if ( hare > RACE_END ) {
        hare = RACE_END;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
int y = 1 + rand() % 10; 
switch(y)
{

    case 1:         //1 or 2
    case 2:
        hare += 0;
        break;
    case 3:         //3 or 4
    case 4:
        hare += 9;
        break;
    case 5:
        hare -= 12;
        break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
        hare += 1;
        break;
    case 9:
    case 10:
         hare -= 2;
         break
    default:
        if ( hare < 1 ) {
            hare = 1;
        } else if ( hare > RACE_END ) {
            hare = RACE_END;
        }
        else
            ++( hare );
        break;
    }
```